# Syntax Error when using Combobox value to filter a query in VBA

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

Good Day. I'm not a developer and I'm not the sharpest tool in the shed to boot, but this is a simple issue I've been battling with for an inordinate amount of time and I'm hoping someone out there in the ether will be kind enough to help with a menial task. I have scoured the answers and forums but I can't quite locate a solution.

I have 3 comboboxes in an Access form which together filter a query [Invoices] down to a single record. I have a piece of VBA I show below in which I am attempting to run a sql query to return the single record into a recordset, using the values of the comboboxes I have selected as filters in a WHERE clause. I will just append the offending piece:

```
JIstat = Forms!Invoices!Combo58.Value
Cname = Forms!Invoices!Combo50.Value
JID = Forms!Invoices!Combo56.Value


Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Invoice Number] FROM Invoices " & _
"WHERE [Job Invoiced?] = '" & JIstat & "'" & _
"AND [Client Name] = '" & Cname & "'" & _
"AND [Job ID] =" & JID)
```

JIstat is a variable that provides a status value (text); Cname provides a client name (text) and JID provides a job identifier (number).

This seems simple enough but when I run it I get Runtime error 3061 too few parameters expected 3. The 3 variables are successfully assigned the correct values but I suspect formatting and syntax are my undoing. I don't have much hair left to lose so any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Added a space on new line of the SQL statement.

```
JIstat = Forms!Invoices!Combo58.Value
Cname = Forms!Invoices!Combo50.Value
JID = Forms!Invoices!Combo56.Value


Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Invoice Number] FROM Invoices " & _
"WHERE [Job Invoiced?] = '" & JIstat & "'" & _
" AND [Client Name] = '" & Cname & "'" & _
" AND [Job ID] =" & JID)
```

Comment: Thanks but still getting Runtime error 3061 too few parameters expected 3

Comment: try creating your sql as a string so you can view exactly what it is creating.   
    `Dim strSQL as string strSQL = "SELECT [Invoice Number] FROM Invoices " & _  
     "WHERE [Job Invoiced?] = '" & JIstat & "'" & _ " AND [Client Name] = '" & Cname & "'" & _  
     " AND [Job ID] =" & JID) debug.print strSQL  `
  
The debug.print will show you exactly what the SQL string is and help you work out why it doesn't think the parameters are there.

Comment: Thank you Santosh and Jenny for your kind assistance. After much anguish I just realised my problem is not so much the syntax but the way I had set up the comboboxes to filter the query required more detail than I was providing for the WHERE condition of the script to run the query successfully and return a single record. I think I may now have a solution which I am currently testing. Best regards.